# compile error in shader ourside of code

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, compute-shader

I have the following attempt at translating the perlin noise to the GPU in

```
unity compute shader:
#pragma kernel CSMain
RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]

//based on http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/

void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{   float res = noise((float)id.x,(float)id.y,0.0f);
    Result[id.xy] = float4(res,res,res,res);
}

int p[256]= {151,160,137,91,90,15,
  131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
  190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
  88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
  77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
  102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
  135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
  5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
  223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
  129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
  251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
  49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
  138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};   

   double fade(double t) { return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10); }
   double lerp(double t, double a, double b) { return a + t * (b - a); }
   double grad(int hash, double x, double y, double z) {
      int h = hash & 15;                      
      double u = h<8 ? x : y,                
             v = h<4 ? y : h==12||h==14 ? x : z;
      return ((h&1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h&2) == 0 ? v : -v);
      }

double noise(float xx, float yy, float zz){
    int X = (int)floor(xx) & 255;
    int Y = (int)floor(yy) & 255;
    int Z = (int)floor(zz) & 255;

    int x = -floor(x);                              
    int y = -floor(y);                                
    int z = -floor(z);
    double u = fade(x);
    double v = fade(y);
    double w = fade(z); 
}
```

However this gives me an error on line 57 (the code is 47 lines long)

```
Shader error in "PerlinClouds.ompute": noise(floatM|halfM|min10floatM|min16floatM) at line 57 (on)
```

Does anybody know what that means? It's not even in my code so I don't quite know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define functions earlier in the file than you first try and use them.

In your noise function:

- You don't return a value.
- You initialise 'x' on the same line as you use it. You might have meant:

  - `int x = -floor(X);`

But maybe you meant:

- `int x = -floor(xx);`

Don't use different case of the same variables (x, xx and X); you appear to have confused yourself and probably anyone reading your code.